# localhost/codeigniter shows index.php instead of welcome_message.php

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi I'm fairly new to server configurations, apache and codeigniter. I installed apache on my ubuntu 16.04, created a html file(index.html) in DocumentRoot of my server (that is var/www/html) just to check if it works. When I enter "localhost" to url bar in firefox it shows the index.html file(So I assume it works?). But when I tried to install codeigniter(by copying all downloaded codeigniter files to a new directory(named codeigniter) under DocumentRoot of my server as stated in the guide) and go to localhost/codeigniter instead of the welcome_message this shows on the page:

```
=')) { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED); } else { error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE); } break; default: header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'The application environment is not set correctly.'; exit(1); // EXIT_ERROR } /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * SYSTEM DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * This variable must contain the name of your "system" directory. * Set the path if it is not in the same directory as this file. */ $system_path = 'system'; /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * APPLICATION DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want this front controller to use a different "application" * directory than the default one you can set its name here. The directory * can also be renamed or relocated anywhere on your server. If you do, * use an absolute (full) server path. * For more info please see the user guide: * * https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/managing_apps.html * * NO TRAILING SLASH! */ $application_folder = 'application'; /* *--------------------------------------------------------------- * VIEW DIRECTORY NAME *--------------------------------------------------------------- * * If you want to move the view directory out of the application * directory, set the path to it here. The directory can be renamed * and relocated anywhere on your server. If blank, it will default * to the standard location inside your application directory. * If you do move this, use an absolute (full) server path. * * NO TRAILING SLASH! */ $view_folder = ''; /* * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * DEFAULT CONTROLLER * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * Normally you will set your default controller in the routes.php file. * You can, however, force a custom routing by hard-coding a * specific controller class/function here. For most applications, you * WILL NOT set your routing here, but it's an option for those * special instances where you might want to override the standard * routing in a specific front controller that shares a common CI installation. * * IMPORTANT: If you set the routing here, NO OTHER controller will be * callable. In essence, this preference limits your application to ONE * specific controller. Leave the function name blank if you need * to call functions dynamically via the URI. * * Un-comment the $routing array below to use this feature */ // The directory name, relative to the "controllers" directory. Leave blank // if your controller is not in a sub-directory within the "controllers" one // $routing['directory'] = ''; // The controller class file name. Example: mycontroller // $routing['controller'] = ''; // The controller function you wish to be called. // $routing['function'] = ''; /* * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * CUSTOM CONFIG VALUES * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * * The $assign_to_config array below will be passed dynamically to the * config class when initialized. This allows you to set custom config * items or override any default config values found in the config.php file. * This can be handy as it permits you to share one application between * multiple front controller files, with each file containing different * config values. * * Un-comment the $assign_to_config array below to use this feature */ // $assign_to_config['name_of_config_item'] = 'value of config item'; // -------------------------------------------------------------------- // END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS. DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE // -------------------------------------------------------------------- /* * --------------------------------------------------------------- * Resolve the system path for increased reliability * --------------------------------------------------------------- */ // Set the current directory correctly for CLI requests if (defined('STDIN')) { chdir(dirname(__FILE__)); } if (($_temp = realpath($system_path)) !== FALSE) { $system_path = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } else { // Ensure there's a trailing slash $system_path = strtr( rtrim($system_path, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR; } // Is the system path correct? if ( ! is_dir($system_path)) { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME); exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } /* * ------------------------------------------------------------------- * Now that we know the path, set the main path constants * ------------------------------------------------------------------- */ // The name of THIS file define('SELF', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)); // Path to the system directory define('BASEPATH', $system_path); // Path to the front controller (this file) directory define('FCPATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // Name of the "system" directory define('SYSDIR', basename(BASEPATH)); // The path to the "application" directory if (is_dir($application_folder)) { if (($_temp = realpath($application_folder)) !== FALSE) { $application_folder = $_temp; } else { $application_folder = strtr( rtrim($application_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } } elseif (is_dir(BASEPATH.$application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $application_folder = BASEPATH.strtr( trim($application_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } else { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } define('APPPATH', $application_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); // The path to the "views" directory if ( ! isset($view_folder[0]) && is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $view_folder = APPPATH.'views'; } elseif (is_dir($view_folder)) { if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE) { $view_folder = $_temp; } else { $view_folder = strtr( rtrim($view_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } } elseif (is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR)) { $view_folder = APPPATH.strtr( trim($view_folder, '/\\'), '/\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR ); } else { header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503); echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF; exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG } define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR); /* * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * LOAD THE BOOTSTRAP FILE * -------------------------------------------------------------------- * * And away we go... */ require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';
```

While playing around codeigniter files I noticed that what is shown on the page is directly the content of the file var/www/html/codeigniter/index.php
after the 78th line. I don't think I changed contents of any file so I have no idea why am I seeing this instead of the welcome_message.

I also tried to create another *view* to see if the problem was about welcome_message by creating the necessary php files 
under *controller* and *views* directories and when I try to go localhost/codeigniter/newview I get 404 not found error.

I would be glad if you could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've installed apache and tested it, but are you sure you've installed php yet? It may be the server just parsing your php as markup and spitting it back at you. If you're on ubuntu 16.04 here's a good guide to installing a LAMP Stack https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: @Ryankozak Following everything on the page you posted worked. But I'm not sure if the problem was php not being installed or changing the priority of index.php in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf. Anyway it worked. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

in Application/Config/Config.php

in thatYou can Set Any default view file

```
$config['index_page'] = ''; or  $config['index_page'] = 'welcome_message.php';
```

Or

You can set Default controller in application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'CONTROLLER Name/METHOD Name(optional)';
```

if you set that default controller it will load that method and view file in that method. so you can set controller and method name to view page which you want.